# update timestamp in laravel model when timestamp set to false in more better way

Tags: laravel

I have set my three model's timestamp to false for not to update the updated_at column. 
now my update function need to update these three models. I wrote the function like below. and I felt it could have been done in more better way. can anyone help me for this.

I want to do it in this same function.

```
   public function update(
      BoxItemUpdateRequest $request,
      ModelA $modelA ,
      ModelB $modelB ,
      ModelC $modelC
   ) {
      $modelA->decrement(
         'total', 
          $request->quantity1- $request->quantity2
      );
      $modelA->timestamps = true;
      $modelA->touch();
      $modelA->save();
      $modelB->decrement(
        'total',
        $request->quantity1- $request->quantity2
      );
      $modelB->timestamps = true;
      $modelB->touch();
      $modelB->save();
      $modelC->quantity_accepted = $request->quantity2;
      $modelC->timestamps = false;
      $modelC->touch();
      $modelC->save();

      return Response::json([
        'status' => HttpStatusCode::HTTP_OK,
      ]);
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are better solutions out there but you can make a `trait` for this that adds some more logic to the `save()` method or your model.

The trait could look like:

```
use Carbon;

trait DoesNotTouchTimestamps // Maybe not the best name
{    
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Save the model to the database.
     *
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function save(array $options = [])
    {
        if (data_get($options, 'touch_updated_at', false)) {
            $this->updated_at = new Carbon;
        }

        return parent::save($options);
    }
}
```

Import it in your models:

```
use DoesNotTouchTimestamps;

class ModelA
{
    use DoesNotTouchTimestamps;
}
```

And call your save like:

```
$modelA->save([
    'touch_updated_at' => true,
]);
```

Comment: So, I can use this any model I want, can I?

Comment: Yes you can, as long as the `parent::save()` method is present (which is the case with Eloquent models).

Comment: Thank you @thomas. I am very much satisfied with you answer. Appreciated.

Comment: This is not going to work with `create()` as create does `save()` internally without any arguments passed to save function.

Comment: @MihirBhende is right. This only applies on the `save()` method. But, if I am not mistaking, the `create()` will eventually call the `save()` function in the trait which has a default value for `$options`. Depending on how you are implementing this logic, the `update()` method will not execute this logic.

Comment: Eloquent in create internally calling `$instance->save();`. So if you pass `touch_updated_at` in the create array, it will no be passed to save. The thing I am mentioning out just because this solution works just for `save()`. However, lot of times we use create or findorcreate etc in which this will not work. With all due respect, overriding the primary methods just to update a timestamp does not seem right to me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Eloquent expects created_at and updated_at columns to exist on your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns automatically managed by Eloquent, set the  $timestamps property on your model to `false`

This means, if you are disabling the timestamps, you can still use pretty basic way of assigning a value manually to it. Switching the value of `timestamps` property to `true` or `false` is not a good way.

Why not use simply `$modelB->updated_at = Carbon::now();`? Since you have told laravel that you are managing the timestamps manually. This helps your code to be readable also if someone tries to see how the timestamps are updating manually,

You can do :

```
<?php 

public function update(BoxItemUpdateRequest $request, ModelA $modelA , ModelB $modelB , ModelC $modelC ) {

  $now = Carbon::now();
  $modelA->decrement('total', $request->quantity1- $request->quantity2);
  $modelA->created_at = $now;
  $modelA->updated_at = $now;
  $modelA->save();



  $modelB->decrement('total', $request->quantity1 - $request->quantity2);
  $modelB->created_at = $now;
  $modelB->updated_at = $now;
  $modelB->save();


  $modelC->quantity_accepted = $request->quantity2;
  $modelC->updated_at = $now;
  $modelC->save();

  return Response::json([
    'status' => HttpStatusCode::HTTP_OK,
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I have both created_at and updated_at in my table. I only update the created_at column when I inserting new value. I update updated_at only when any update done in that table. I need both column but update in different actions

Comment: Yes by the method I mentioned you can set either `created_at` or `updated_at` as per your logic anytime.